# how to find corresponding column value in a data frame based on highest value in another column

Tags: r

from this data frame, I want to filter which season there were the highest number of goals

it should display 2011-2012

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput()` and paste your data right into your question. That lets anyone who wants to help you copy it right into R. Don't post images of data or code. They are not searchable and can mess with screen readers.  What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

which.max?

eg:

```
df[which.max(df$goals),]
```

Updated for OPs comment, to get just just the season:

```
df[which.max(df$goals),1]
```

Comment: it's returning the entire row, but I just need 2011-2012, so that I can print it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example dataset

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(season = c("2006-2007", "2007-2008", "2008-2009", "2009-2010"),
                 goals = c(800, 900, 1000, 1200))
```

And here is the code. The result is just the season with the highest goals.

```
df %>% 
  filter(goals == max(goals, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  pull(season)
```